# Why won't `cat` append to a `file` connection?

Tags: r

I ran these two code blocks, expecting the same output

```
cattest <- file("cattest.txt")
cat("First thing", file = cattest)
cat("Second thing", file = cattest, append = TRUE)
close(cattest)

sink("cattest_sink.txt")
cat("First thing")
cat("Second thing")
sink()
```

But the resulting `cattest.txt` contains only "Second thing", whereas the `cattest_sink.txt` includes what I expected, "First thingSecond thing". Why is the `append` argument ignored with the file connection?

I'm on 64bit R 3.0.1 on Windows, in case it matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's what `?cat` says it will do if `file` is not the name of a file.

> append: logical. Only used if the argument 'file' is the name of file
>             (and not a connection or '"|cmd"').  If 'TRUE' output will be
>             appended to 'file'; otherwise, it will overwrite the contents
>             of 'file'.

Comment: The desired effect can be achieved using `cat(c("First thing", "Second thing"), sep = "\n", file = cattest)`.

Comment: @RichieCotton: while that solves this simple example, I doubt it's suitable for the actual problem the OP faced.  I was thinking something like `cat("2nd thing", file=summary(cattest)$description, append=TRUE)` could work, but I didn't test.

Answer (score 5):

One way to append text using `cat` is to open a file connection of mode `a`.

```
cattest <- file("cattest.txt")
cat("First thing", file = cattest, fill = TRUE)
close(cattest)

cattest <- file("cattest.txt", open = "a")
cat("Second thing", file = cattest)
close(cattest)
```