# Avoid overwriting a text file in R

Tags: r, append

I have the following simple R code:

```
sink("output.txt", type=c("output", "message"))
cat("Hello", append = TRUE)
cat("World", append = TRUE)
sink(NULL)
```

It just writes the R console into a text file. I want to put it in an R source file (".r") and run it multiple times. I want to have the output as follows:

```
file.show("output.txt")
Hello
World
Hello
World
```

If I run it two times, I now see:

```
Hello
World
```

It looks like it has been overwritten.

Comment: Try `sink("output.txt", type=c("output", "message"), append=TRUE)`

Comment: I ran into this problem too: <http://stackoverflow.com/q/17710469/903061>. If you read `?cat`, the `append` argument only matters if you're using the `file` argument of `cat`.

Comment: @RichardScriven: You're right! sink() has its own append and as you said I don't even need to use append as long as I do not call sink(NULL). Please post your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sink()` has its own `append` argument. And as Gregor mentioned, `append` in `cat()` only works when `file` is used.

However, you don't need to use `append` at all if you put all the `cat()` calls between the `sink()` calls, as `sink()` will continue to append to the file until you call `sink(NULL)`

But for your case, I think you want to do something like this for your `sink()` chunk:

```
sink("output.txt", type=c("output", "message"), append = TRUE)
cat("Hello", "\n")
cat("World", "\n")
sink(NULL)
```

Or more simply,

```
sink("output.txt", type=c("output", "message"), append = TRUE)
cat("Hello", "World", sep = "\n")
sink(NULL)
```

Repeating this operation twice, we have created the file and appended to it

```
Hello
World
Hello
World
```